# Why does Stack Overflow not honor the order of tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I just posted [a question related to Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109475/make-capybara-use-multiple-tabs-not-windows), and after tagging it as such added the 'ruby' tag as well, since (of course) Capybara is used from and written in Ruby.

Although 'capybara' was the first tag, Stack Overflow chose 'ruby' as the primary tag to display in the title.  Why is this?  What are the effects of this?  Is there any way to change this other than just removing the 'ruby' tag?

Because Ruby is a much more general category than Capybara, it seems to me that making 'capybara' the primary tag makes more sense and will be more likely to make it stand out to the right people.  Is this correct?  But on the other hand, a good portion of Rubyists know something about Capybara, so I'd like to keep the 'ruby' tag there too, so they notice it too.

Answer (score 8):

Tags are displayed based on the order of the number of questions associated with them, not the order in which they were entered.

There is no way to change that ordering.

Comment: Yes, but why?  Or perhaps I should assume the answer: because it seemed like a good idea at the time (or just simpler to implement), and no one has bothered to fix the result of past bad decisions.

Comment: @iconoclast I've never seen it as a problem in all the time I've been using SO.  You're more than welcome to request a change of the functionality if you want, but I imagine you're not going to find most people feeling that it was a bad decision to begin with.